# how its work i am trying user uid in firebaseanimated list

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

```
@override
  User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  Query dbRef =FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('user').child(widget.user!.uid);
  Widget listItem({required Map student})  {
    // TODO: implement build
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }
```

[image]

error
The instance member 'widget' can't be accessed in an initializer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my take on your question:

Replace `widget.user!.uid` with `user!.uid`

Your code will look something like this.

```dart
@override
  Widget listItem({required Map student})  {
    User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    Query dbRef =FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('user').child(user!.uid);
    // TODO: implement build
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }
```

Check for the value of user to ensure it is not null.

Comment: body: FirebaseAnimatedList(
           query: dbRef,

now in body dbRef is undefined  name

Comment: looks like this is thrown in a different part of your code.